# In Django, how do I change group of user using template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-authentication

I have made a custom group.
I want to display all groups from database using django template with radio button, so that the user can select only one from available group.

radio button of current user's group should be selected & I should be able to change it using template.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Make one template like this: -**

`radio_button.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form action="">
    {% for option in groups%}
      {% if option == selected_item%}
        <input type="radio" name="group" value="{{option}}" checked>{{option}}<br>
      {%else%}
      <input type="radio" name="group" value="{{option}}">{{option}}<br>
      {%endif%}
    {% endfor %}
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Views.py:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    t=get_template('radio_button.html')
    groups = ["Group-A","Group-B","Group-C","Group-D","Group-E"]  #bring data from database or use static list
    selected_item = "Group-C"
    data = {"groups":groups,"selected_item":selected_item}
    html=t.render(Context(data))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^index/$',index),
)
```

Comment: Not Quite what I am looking for. It should display groups from database. & current user's group should be selected.

Comment: updated my answer. look into it.you can bring options and selected_item from database using your database query.

Comment: i want to display all user groups present as radio buttons so that user can select only one group while creating a user account & on save button, currently selected user group should be set as group of new user account.